# Color Picker seems to be giving a null value in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, color-picker

I am trying to use a Color Picker to set the stroke of a shape in JFX. It seems to be returning a null value because the stroke of the shape is clear. Is there something I'm missing here?

```
ColorPicker strokeC = new ColorPicker();
stroke = strokeC.getValue();

currentCircle.setStroke(stroke);
```

Comment: "seems to be"? Is it `null` or not? Has the user chosen something? Also, I assume `strokeC` instead of `strokeF` is just a typo in the question.

Comment: yes that is a typo, but it is null, im sure

Comment: What color did you select in the color picker? Have you tried a `System.out.println(stroke);` to check?

Comment: the current cirle line is somewhere else in the program, all variables are class level so they are visible. The user is supposed to pick a color from color picker and the circle is supposed to be that color, but it is always null

Comment: You should create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) from scratch and edit your question to include it.

Comment: i just tried the sout(stroke) and it gave "0xffffffff"

Comment: ok, anything i select within the color picker is that value